# How can I compare two array of characters?

Tags: c, string, logical-operators

In my code I've problem in if statement. I feel the code is correct. The 
ASCII value for first character array is retrieved. But, the ASCII value 
of second character array remains 0.
Help me to solve this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
  char team1[50],team2[50];
  int testcase,rounds,i=0,j,l,count=0,ascii1,ascii2;
  scanf("%d",&testcase);
  while(i<testcase)
  {
    scanf("%d",&rounds);
    scanf("%s",team2);
    scanf("%s",team1);
    printf("team2..%s\n",team2);

    for(l=0;l<rounds;l++)
    {
      for(j=l;j<rounds;j++); //<--- Don't do this...
      {
      ascii1=team1[l];
      ascii2=team2[j];
      if(ascii1==ascii2)   
      {
        count+=1;
      }
      printf("count..%d\n",count);
      }
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
    i++;    
  }
}
```

The number of same characters should be displayed.
For exmaple:
Input:

```
1
4
asdf
qwsa
```

Output:

```
2
```

Comment: *I feel the code is correct* - code is correct when it is doing the thing it is supposed to do. Otherwise it is not.

Comment: Please enable warnings.  That would have saved you a lot of time.

Comment: why not use strcmp, is it a homework or something

Comment: regarding: `void main()`  there are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function.  (regardless of what some compilers may allow)  Those signatures are: `int main( void )`  and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: regarding: `for(j=l;j<rounds;j++);` The trailing semicolon ';' means an empty body for the `for()` code block.  Strongly suggest removing that trailing semicolon ';'

Comment: OT: regarding `scanf("%s",team2);` and other calls to `scanf()`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]'  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Answer (score 4):

You have a redundant (wrong) semicolon (`;`) after the second `for`, making it loop over an empty block. Remove it, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(l=0;l<rounds;l++)
{
ascii1=team1[l];
for(j=l;j<rounds;j++)
{
ascii2=team2[j];
if(ascii1==ascii2)   
{
count+=1;
}
}
}
```

this will work only for your given input
( 
1
4
asdf
qwsa
)
if you are changing the input then code will also change like for input
asdf and qsas